# Как создать связку видеоплеера клиент-сервер, что б видео транслировалось фрагментами и его было невозможно скачать?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asp.net-core

Как создать связку видеоплеера клиент-сервер (сервер Node.js либо Asp.net Core), что б видео транслировалось фрагментами и его было невозможно скачать?
Ну либо усложнить скачивание, понимаю, что тот кто хочет - скачает, но что б это заставляло попотеть....
Как я понимаю сервер должен фрагменты посылать зашифрованные и на клиенте этот поток расшифровывается и собирается видеофайл.
Но как-то так, что б расширения браузера его не скачали так просто....

Comment: По такому принципу сейчас работает YouTube и другие аналогичные источники и ничто не помешало придумать уйму альтернативных механизмов скачиваний из данных источников. Если хотите изобрести что-то специфическое, то вероятно здесь дело не в технологиях, а в устройствах шифрования и дешифрования. Но даже инвестировав миллионы пиастров в разработку, вам никогда не удастся решить эту проблему в полной мере. Потому как на каждый источник вещания всегда найдется источник приема этого вещания и взлома. Стоит ли так сильно заморачиваться? Даже YouTube со своими миллиардами не решил эту задачу.

Answer (score 0):

Я разраб PHP но в теории я бы не давал вообще ссылку на видео. Например генерим на лету поток. То есть файл который отдает нужный content-type с видео. Понятно что можно засунуть в утилитку ссылку на поток но ссылка может постоянно меняться например от sessionId или чего-то подобного. Это усложнит задачу. разделять видео на фрагменты по моему при нагрузке ваш сервер скажет: "я устал, прощайте" уже при 500 оналйна.